# Интернет магазин - реализация корзины

Tags: javascript

Пишу интернет магазин - нужно реализовать корзину, что бы пользователь мог зайди в нее. Должна быть возможность удалить товары из корзины, если посетитель передумал покупать и совершать заказ.

Так как у меня небольшой практический опыт, то возник вопрос:

Как хранить товары в корзине?

У меня только две идеи:

1. Это создать объект на js и товары хранить в массиве из объектов. А при заказе данные отправить на сервер.
2. Создавать таблицу в БД, и при каждом добавлении/удалении из корзины делать ajax запрос серверу для добавления или удаления из бд.Или на сервере в массиве хранить?

Comment: @vasyavasya интересно, а какие у вас причины хранить эти данные на сервере, особенно в базе? Что-то особых плюсов не видно

Answer (score 1):

Если задача действительно требует хранения содержимого корзины на сервере, храните ее в таблице id пользователя, id товара, количество. В таком случае реализация будет проще, чем в случае со всем набором (хоть в виде объекта, хоть в виде массива) и гибче (если потом встанет задача подчищать корзину от устаревших позиций товаров или что-то аналогичное.

Другой вариант - хранить товары в сессии пользователя. Но в этом случае данные могут быть легко потеряны при окончании сессии.

Но может все же вам стоит хранить эту информацию в cookies или localStorage браузера клиента?

В общем, реализация зависит от тонкостей задачи.